# Is there a correct way to join multiple DB tables in Spring + Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, join

I've spent a second day reading and testing the matter and it doesn't seem to go anywhere.

First the database has 4 main tables:

- Recruits,
- Tests,
- Evaluators,
- Reviews,
- and a few connecting tables with foreign keys between them (I can modify the connections for now).

Here's a visual of the tables' connections: [image]

I want to connect all of them in an `@Entity` object that can call each one of their corresponding attributes. There seem to be two(???) ways to join the tables. First example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recruits")
public class Recruit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="first_name")
...
    attributes
    ...

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
        name="current_score",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="recruit_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="test_id"))
private List<Test> tests;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL ) 
@JoinColumn(name="recruit_id")
private List<CurrentScore> currentScore;
```

Here the Recruit entity connects to the Test table and then to the Current Score table. 
This doesn't seem right, because the **current score** must correspond to a specific **test** and even though from what I've tried they do, there doesn't seem to be any certainty.

The second way I can think of is in the `RecruitDAOImplementation` class:

```
@Override
public List<Recruit> getAllRecruits() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query<Recruit> currentQuery = 
            session.createQuery("from Recruit", Recruit.class);

    List<Recruit> allRecruits = currentQuery.getResultList();

    return allRecruits;
}
```

I haven't seen it done here in any of the tutorials, but if anyone can confirm it is the correct way and what exactly should it return - I'd gladly do it.

If anyone has any example how to improve/correct those two solutions, has another one in mind or a link to an explanation, that would really help!

Comment: `@Column(name="id") private int id;` in this case your name is redundant

Comment: _the current score must correspond to a specific test_ Then it shouldn't be a `List<Test>` with 1:n, it should a specific test (like you said) class with it's score in it. Or is there any misunderstanding?

Comment: List<Test> has a ManyToMany relationship with Recruit. You are suggesting that I should put CurrentScore list in tests and then use Tests?

Comment: But you said _the current score must correspond** to a specific** test_ when they have a n:n relation?!

Comment: Let's say we have 2 types of **Tests** - C# and Java. Each of those can be done many times, by many **Recruits**, but each **Recruit** will have only one **Current Score** for a specific **Test** type. Do you think the relationship 1:n or n:n should be changed for any of those?

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear out of your question. What with creating a `Score` class with 1:1 to `Test` and 1:1 to `Recruit`. It's like you would do on relational databases.

Comment: Should I do it as an Entity with an Annotation like the first example, or a session query like the second?

Comment: I think - as you might already have a connection table - you should create an `@Entity` for this one mapping both together. - As I personally would prefer document based database systems for such cases, I can't give you a final advice. Just an opinion.